# How to combine 'NESTED PATH` values using JSON_TABLE to fetch a nested JSON array?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, sql-update, mysql-json

I have a Json array while looks as below

```
[{"keyId": "aded5b0107bb5a936604bcb6f", "keyNames": ["abc1, abc2"], "keyDesc": "test"}]
```

I am using JSON_TABLE to fetch all the values and I have written the following query:

```
SELECT j.keyId, j.keyNames, j.keyDesc
FROM asknow a, JSON_TABLE(value, '$[*]' 
    COLUMNS(
      keyId TEXT PATH '$.keyId',
      NESTED PATH '$.keyNames[*]' COLUMNS (keyNames TEXT PATH '$'),
      keyDesc TEXT PATH '$.keyDesc')
    ) AS j;
```

I am getting following output:

```
keyId                        keyNames   keyDesc
aded5b0107bb5a936604bcb6f    abc1       test
aded5b0107bb5a936604bcb6f    abc2       test
```

How to modify the query so as to combine the values into a single string `"abc1, abc2"`?

> Desired Output:

```
keyId                        keyNames   keyDesc
aded5b0107bb5a936604bcb6f    abc1, abc2       test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `json_table` columns with `group_concat(`) to group multiple rows extracted from the inner array.

```
SELECT j.keyId, group_concat(distinct j.keyNames) as keyNames, j.keyDesc
FROM JSON_TABLE(@temp, '$[*]' 
    COLUMNS(
      keyId TEXT PATH '$.keyId',
      NESTED PATH '$.keyNames[*]' COLUMNS (keyNames TEXT PATH '$'),
      keyDesc TEXT PATH '$.keyDesc')
    ) AS j
group by j.keyId, j.keyDesc;
```

I am not sure why you have used `asknow a` table in your query, so ignoring it for now. I have used MySQL 8.0.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4cf8aeaf7edd8c83a8c91aa547e25a0)